# VBA excel comp ability mode issue

Tags: vba, excel

Good afternoon everyone. I create a first ever Macro with some of your help and it worked fine until I tested with actual source file that comes from Service-Now report and the only option there .XLS so when I open Source file in Excel 2013 it open in Compatibility Mode and macro give me 'Run time error '9' "Subscript out of range". What should I do to make it work?

```
Sub HELLO()

Dim x As Workbook


Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Clear

'## Open  workbook first:
Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\500722\Desktop\dashboard\task.xls")


'Now, transfer values from x to y:
Sheet1.Cells(1, 1) = x.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
With x.Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange
'Now, paste to y worksheet:
    Sheet1.Range("A1").Resize( _
        .Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) = .Value

End With

x.Close


End Sub
```

Comment: (a) Which line gives the error?  (b) Does task.xls contain a sheet called "Sheet1"?

Comment: P.S.  It is also polite to respond to questions raised in comments - I just noticed that you still haven't responded to a comment I left on your first question.  And it is also a good idea to mark answers as "accepted" once they solve your problem.

Comment: @YowE3K Yes it has a sheet 1 with name page1 and  this line Sheet1.Cells(1, 1) = x.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")

Comment: @YowE3K i am sorry i didnt saw the comment and yes it has a sheet 1 with name page1 and this line Sheet1.Cells(1, 1) = x.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")

Comment: The comment I was referring to, that hasn't been responded to, is on the first question you raised (yesterday some time).  I wasn't worried about the comment on this one yet - people can't stay online all the time, so it is natural for comments not to be responded to immediately.  But to raise 3 new questions without answering queries on the first question is not polite.

Comment: @YowE3K Wow it worked i am so stupid i tried page1 also but it didnt worked and forgot there is a space between page and 1..Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 0):

As you don't have a worksheet called "Sheet1" in the workbook you opened, your code will fail when you try to access that sheet.

Change all occurrences of `x.Sheets("Sheet1")` to `x.Sheets("Page1")` and your problem will probably go away.